# questions about a function that act like scanf

Tags: c++

I am wondering about the function below.

```
inline int nextInt()
{
    register int s = 0, ch;
    for (ch = getchar(); ch < '0' || ch > '9'; ch = getchar());
    for (s = ch - '0', ch = getchar(); ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'; ch = getchar())
        s = s * 10 + ch - '0';
    return s;
}
```

I know that this function behaviors scanf function-like by returning the integer value. However, I didn't understand the function's detailed procedure because many variables are in for loops and it is a little bit confused to me to understand correctly. Even though I copied and pasted them on my visual studio and see each value in variables by printf, but I failed to know what they are doing.

Could you explain above codes to me about what they are doing line by line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First line

```
register int s = 0, ch;
```

The `register` keyword is an outdated storage specifier telling the compiler to keep a value in a processor register (outdated because nowadays the compilers are very good at making that decision themselves, and the register keyword is ignored anyway).

From the presence of this keyword, I conclude that this is very old code. For any modern compiler, the above can safely replaced with

```
int s = 0, ch;
```

## Second line

```
for (ch = getchar(); ch < '0' || ch > '9'; ch = getchar());
```

Let's rewrite this into the equivalent `while` loop:

```
ch = getchar();
while (ch < '0' || ch > '9')
{
  ch = getchar();
}
```

Now it's easier to see what it does: It reads a character, and as long as it is not a digit, discards it and reads the next character.

In the name of DRY (don't repeat yourself), it would better be written using a do while loop:

```
do
{
  ch = getchar();
} while (ch < '0' || ch > '9');
```

## Third and fourth line

```
for (s = ch - '0', ch = getchar(); ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'; ch = getchar())
    s = s * 10 + ch - '0';
```

Let's again replace it with an equivalent while loop:

```
s = ch - '0', ch = getchar();
while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
{
  s = s * 10 + ch - '0';
  ch = getchar();
}
```

The `s = ch - '0', ch = getchar()` is just two expression statements combined with the comma operator. The comma operator just ignores the value of its first argument after evaluating it, and returns the value of the second. It is used here because there can only be one initializer statement in a `for` and for some reason the author of that code thought he must cram both in there. So let's split it now in two statements:

```
s = ch - '0';
ch = getchar();
```

The expression `ch - '0'` just evaluates the value of the digit. This uses the fact that the type `char` actually is an integer type, and `0` really is the character code for the digit `0`. Also it makes use of the requirement that all ten digits are consecutive in the character set.

The variable `s` stores the integer read so far. Since so far only one digit has been read, the integer read so far is just the value of the digit we read.

The second statement here of course just reads the next character.

The loop now runs as long as the next character read is still a digit.

The statement

```
s = s * 10 + ch - '0'
```

effectively appends the next digit to `s`. Multiplying by 10 just "appends a zero", and adding (ch - '0') then replaces that final 0 with the digit value.

Note that to avoid overflow (and thus undefined behaviour) when reading a number close to `INT_MAX`, this should actually read

```
s = s * 10 + (ch - '0');
```

Alternatively, given that this code can only read positive numbers anyway, the author could just have used an unsigned type, as there overflow behaviour is well defined.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (ch = getchar(); ch < '0' || ch > '9'; ch = getchar());
```

reads and ignores characters until it gets something in the range 0-9.

```
for (s = ch - '0', ch = getchar(); ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'; ch = getchar())
    s = s * 10 + ch - '0';
```

stores the numeric value of the last-read ascii character into s (e.g. '1' puts 1 into s). Then it reads the next character into ch. Then it tests if ch is a numeric digit. If so, it multiplies the existing value of s by 10 and adds the numeric value of ch. Now it reads another character and proceeds to the test again.

If you type 123, it reads '1' and stores 1 into s. Then it reads '2', multiplies s (1) by 10 (10) and adds 2 (12). Then it reads '3', multiplies s (12) by 10 (120) and adds 3 (123).

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's break it down:

```
inline int nextInt()
```

The `inline` keyword is a hint to the compiler that this function is small and should be "inlined" (basically a little optimization that inserts the function into source code rather than making it a function call).

```
    register int s = 0, ch;
```

The `register` keyword, for all practical intents and purposes and in 99.99% of cases, is semantically meaningless, making this line equivalent to `int s = 0, ch;`.

```
    for (ch = getchar(); ch < '0' || ch > '9'; ch = getchar());
```

This line is a little silly. It's actually calling `getchar()` twice, meaning that it pulls in (potentially) two characters, compares one of them to ensure it's between 0 and 9, and keeps going if it isn't. A better way to write this might be `do ch = getchar(); while (ch < '0' || ch > '9');`.

```
for (s = ch - '0', ch = getchar(); ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'; ch = getchar())
    s = s * 10 + ch - '0';
```

These two lines, in effect, keep multiplying `s` by 10 while pushing a new integer into the ones column as long as the user keeps entering integers. If the user enters `8 1 3 4`, the resulting integer will be 8134.